# Regex: define a particular group and avoid repeating it each time

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

My problem is that I've created a very long and unreadable regex to check if a particular input is well-formed.

My regex: `^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?\|([A-Z]{2}((\+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?(\*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?|(\*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?(\+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?),)*[A-Z]{2}((\+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?(\*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?|(\*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?(\+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))?)( \"([^\"])+\")?)$`

This isn't readable, and it is very easy to forget what it does...

**Is there a way to define a "variable" and use it multiple times in the regex?** For example if I define `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` as `#number#` my regex would be more readable:

`^(#number#\|([A-Z]{2}((\+(#number#))?(\*(#number#))?|(\*(#number#))?(\+(#number#))?),)*[A-Z]{2}((\+(#number#))?(\*(#number#))?|(\*(#float_number#))?(\+(#number#))?)( \"([^\"])+\")?)$`